# struct unpack error when converting datetime(2) datatype in SQL Server to string

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc, python-datetime

```
def datetime_as_string(raw_bytes):
     #
    tup = struct.unpack('8h', raw_bytes)
    print(tup)
    return datetime.datetime(tup[0], tup[1], tup[2], tup[3], tup[4], tup[5], 0).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

I am writing this function to unpack `datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 18, 13, 42, 31, 316666)` with data type `datetime2(7)` in SQL Server to convert it to a string but I am unable to do this as it unpacks to `(2022, 11, 18, 13, 42, 31, -3252, 4831)` whereas I was expecting it to unpack it to `(2022, 11, 18, 13, 42, 31, 316666)`.

I am unable to figure out how to if condition to check between `datetime2(7)` and `datetime`. When I don't use the output converter in pyodbc the query returned is like this

```
('103345', datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 9, 13, 51, 42, 856667), datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 9, 13, 51, 42, 856667), '2022-06-09', 'ENTRY', 'ENTRY')
```

and I want it to be something like this

```
('103345', '2022-06-09 13:51:42.856667', '2022-06-09 13:51:42.856667', '2022-06-09', 'ENTRY', 'ENTRY')
```

Kindly help me figure where I might be doing wrong.

The other part of my script which is working correctly and converting `date` datatype to string when I comment the above function.

```
def convert_date_to_string(raw_bytes):
    tup = struct.unpack('3h', raw_bytes)
    # print(tup)
    return datetime.date(tup[0], tup[1], tup[2]).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    
# check if the connection is successful
def test_query():
    try:
        conn = po.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
        # add converter for datetime and date
        conn.add_output_converter(po.SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP, datetime_as_string)
        conn.add_output_converter(po.SQL_TYPE_DATE, convert_date_to_string)
        
        print("Connection Successful")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Connection Failed")
        print(e)
```

Tldr; I am trying to get output of sql query in pyodc as string rather than `datetime.datetime()` object for which I wrote a output converter function and I get this error

> struct unpack error 8 bytes buffer required

or

> unpacking incorrectly

Comment: What makes you think dates and datetimes are structured like that? Technically an `8h` buffer is 8 short integers, so 16 bytes.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning so what should be it then? ```2i``` ?

Comment: At the TDS layer they're packed like this... [2.2.5.5.1.8 Dates and Times](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/786f5b8a-f87d-4980-9070-b9b7274c681d).

Comment: Thanks @AlwaysLearning, I was able to figure out the solution, thanks for pointing out! also I didn't need to change the function for date it worked as it is!